# cocoa read text to custom data format, porting from sgi

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to port an academic research application that I wrote for SGI IRIX 10 years ago, to native Mac OS X, because of Apple's disconcern about X11 and glx, which never gave satisfying results for the program to properly run.
On the other hand, using Apple's port of GLUT introduces threading problems between visualization and sonification callbacks which I find almost impossible to debug. So rewriting in Cocoa should be the obvious solution.

However, when trying to read a data text file I already encounter a wall of problems, because of a custom file scanning and data retrieving routine I need. Once opened by means of 
- (IBAction)openExistingDocument:(id)sender 
and
NSOpenPanel* 
file gets "flockfile'd" for all reading methods and access other than

**dataString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filepath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];**

which would be in itself ok, if I only knew where and how to declare and return the variable
dataString, so it can be passed to my custom data extraction and modification routines, and mapped to a three-dimensional array of seven-member program-defined int/float/double structs (whose dimensions can't be assumed before the entire string/file gets analyzed.

On the other hand **NSOpenGLPixelFormat** forces into using pre-defined data types, which make recalculations somewhat inpractical.

Since I have to deal with about 20000+ lines of code to port, I prefer to understand the mechanisms of Cocoa better then the on level of pre-defined data types and built-in callbacks, which are being covered in the technical documentation, tutorials and sample code of Cocoa and Xcode.

If someone could point me at a relevant source, where I could learn more about real possibilities and bottlenecks of Cocoa, it would help me make a better decision in assuming porting strategies.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working answer to my question - hope it can contribute to someone with similar questions. This is my specific case, else actual read and data formatting function will look differently. It's not meant to serve as case example of OSX coding, just as a simple practical code solving the question.

There are two important parts in the code:

1. The part which belongs to the NSOpenPanel code, invoking a plain-C file reading function:

   ```
   //code inside OpenDialog IBAction's completion handler
   //...   ...   ...
   fileName = [[files objectAtIndex:i] path];//*NOT* absoluteString - no URLs in Unix!
   //...   ...   ...
   str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Raw data file: %s", openFile([fileName UTF8String],self->swapRaw)];
   ```
2. The actual, plain-C, Unix-style file reading function:

   ```
   char *openFile(const char file[1024], BOOL swap)
   {
   FILE *f = fopen(file, "r");
   char *d;
   UInt32 size;

   //assuming fBuffer and fBuffersize are global variables
   if(fBuffersize > 0){
   free(fBuffer);
   fBuffersize = 0;
   }

   if (f != NULL){        
   if((size = getSize(f, file)) == 0) 
   {
       d = "size_error";
       fclose(f);
       return d;
   }

   fBuffer  = calloc(size, sizeof(Float32));
   fBuffersize = size;        
   fread(fBuffer,sizeof(Float32),size, f);
   fclose(f);

   //local swap function if format not native-endian
   if(swap) swapFloat32Buffer(fBuffer, fBuffersize);
   d = "Success";            
   }   
   return d;
   }
   ```

Comment: For strings that you are going to pass to a unix file API, use `fileSystemRepresentation` instead of just `UTF8String`, as the former will properly encode unicode characters for the file APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using class methods? Do you need to use NSData instead of NSString? One way you can get the contents of an NSString as a C string is using [theStr UTF8String].